# Как сохранять переменные типа bool в файл формата json?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-android

Всем привет.
Возникла такая проблема, не знаю как сохранить данные переменных bool.
Есть магазин внутриигровых покупок и после покупки какого либо предмета у меня пропадает кнопка покупки, но после перезапуска игры эта кнопка всё равно есть.
Так вот как сохранить данные о покупке? Точнее данные того, что у меня должна пропасть кнопка покупки.
Код плохо написан, тк новичек

```
public Image[] Guns;
public GameObject shop;
public GameObject game;
public GameObject[] Buybutton;

public Text Coins;

public Button[] buttons;
public int[] price;






void Start()
{
    Guns[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("g")].color = Color.white;
}

public void Update() 
{
    if (shop.activeSelf == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        shop.SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (game.activeSelf == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        game.SetActive(false);
    }

    Coins.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coinsFinal").ToString();
}

public void OnClickShop() 
{
    shop.SetActive(true);
}

public void OnClickPlay() 
{
    game.SetActive(true);
}

public void Arena()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
}

public void NewGame() 
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
}

public void Exit() 
{
    Application.Quit();
}

public void gunChanger(int gun) 
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("g", gun);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    switch (gun) 
    {
        case 0:
            Guns[gun].color = Color.white;
            Guns[gun + 1].color = Color.black;
        break;
        case 1:
            Guns[gun].color = Color.white;
            Guns[gun - 1].color = Color.black;
        break;
    }
}

public void OnBuyClick() 
{
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coinsFinal") >= price[1])
    {
         Buybutton[1].SetActive(false);
        buttons[1].interactable = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coinsFinal", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coinsFinal") - price[1]);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> bool <--> int

> true <-->  1

> false <--> 0

```
var foo = true;
// Сохраняем значение переменной в PlayerPrefs, если true то 1, иначе 0
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("foo", foo?1:0);
// Забираем значение из PlayerPrefs
foo = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("foo")==1;
```

[Тут](https://forum.unity.com/threads/playerprefs-setbool-and-playerprefs-getbool.12795/) еще варианты реализации глянуть можно

Comment: `?true:false` - лишнее

Comment: То есть я могу сделать ссылку на массив кнопок?

Comment: Вообще про массив я никогда не использовал, но вроде гуглится такая штука http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ArrayPrefs2#C.23_-_PlayerPrefsX.cs , по мне так лучше хранить значения для кнопок в строке типа "1000111..." а потом парсить значения @sweet74r

Comment: Спасибо, думаю разберусь)

Comment: @sweet74r отметьте тогда ответ галочкой)

Comment: О не знал о такой возможности, ещё раз спасибо!:)